# Как разместить подпись к CheckBox слева от "квадратика"?

Tags: java, android

Нужно перенести текст у CheckBox в левую сторону.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Например, вот так:

   ```
   <Checkbox
       ...
       android:button="@null"
       android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
   ```
2. Можно заменить на такой `LinearLayout`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="text"/>
   <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/chb"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Для API 17+ все проще. Просто добавить в `CheckBox` атрибут:

   ```
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"
   ```